# Handling Redirect with URL that has multiple PK

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm new to Django and having trouble redirecting after the AddContactEvent form has been filled out. After submitting the form, here is the redirect error:

> No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a
>   get_absolute_url method on the Model.

I am having trouble figuring out how to redirect it since the AddContactEvent url `path('contacts/<int:pk1>/addcontactevent)`
only has one pk. In the EventDetail url there are clearly two pk which would have the contact pk and the event pk. The EventDetail page seems to be creating, but I can't get it to redirect to that page due to multiple PK. how would you handle the redirect?

urls.py

```
    path('contacts/<int:pk>', contact_detail.as_view(), name="contact_detail"),
    path('contacts/<int:pk1>/addcontactevent', AddContactEvent.as_view(), name="addcontactevent"),
    path('contacts/<int:pk1>/event/<int:pk2>/update', UpdateContactEvent.as_view(), name="updatecontactevent"),
    path('contacts/<int:pk1>/event/<int:pk2>', EventDetail.as_view(), name="eventdetail"),
```

views.py

```
class AddContactEvent(CreateView):
    form_class = ContactEventForm
    template_name = 'crm/contactevent.html'
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Overridden so we can make sure the `Ipsum` instance exists
        before going any further.
        """
        self.contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=kwargs['pk1'])
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        """ Save the form instance. """
        contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=self.kwargs['pk1'])
        form.instance.contact = contact
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class UpdateContactEvent(UpdateView):
    model = Event
    def get_object(self):
        pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
        pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
        contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=pk1)
        event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk2)
        return event

class DeleteContactEvent(DeleteView):
    model = Event

class EventDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'crm/eventdetail.html'
    model = Event
    def get_object(self):
        pk1 = self.kwargs['pk1']
        pk2 = self.kwargs['pk2']
        contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=pk1)
        event = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=pk2)
        return event
```

Comment: After the `ContactEventForm` has been saved will it not have the `pk` for the new event? You already have the contact pk `self.kwargs['pk1']`

Comment: @IainShelvington isn't pk1 in that case = contact id? don't we need to pass the event id somehow?

Answer (score 0):

one way to get rid of the error is to define a get absolute url in contact model

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("contact_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a saved Event object (which has a pk) and you have the contact pk

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('eventdetail', kwargs={'pk1': self.kwargs['pk1'], 'pk2': self.object.pk})
```